# How can I customize BounceInterpolator from xml?

Tags: android, android-animation

I can create a custom bounce interpolator from java code like this:

```
public class CustomBounceInterpolator implements android.view.animation.Interpolator {

    double mAmplitude = 1;
    double mFrequency = 10;

    public CustomBounceInterpolator(double amplitude, double frequency) {
        mAmplitude = amplitude;
        mFrequency = frequency;
    }

    public float getInterpolation(float time) {
        return (float) (-1 * Math.pow(Math.E, -time / mAmplitude) *
            Math.cos(mFrequency * time) + 1);
    }
}
```

But I want to create a custom bounce interpolator from xml because I use it as my Dialog Fragment's enter animation like this:

```
getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.dialogAnimation;

<style name="dialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_bottom_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_top_out</item>
</style>
```

So, is there any way I can use my custom bounce animation as my fragment's enter animation, or can I define this custom bounce interpolator in an xml file?

Thanks.